# Basic questions about Linear Mappings.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

*What is the difference between a change of basis and a simple linear transformation?*
Be ***A*** the matrix expressing the linear mapping ***T*** from  **U** to **W**.
Now, we know that columns of ***A*** represent the decomposition of the basis of **U** along the basis of **W**.
So, if domain and range of the mapping do have the same basis (say the standard basis), the matrix ***A*** need to be the identity.
Consequently, it appears that any matrix ***A*** that is not ***I***, carries a change of basis, and (square) trasformations between spaces with the same basis do NOT really happen. Is that right?

Also, I'm wondering why major matrix decompositions (Like eigendecomposition, spectral decomposition, and above all, the SVD), express a given transformation as a change of basis, followed by shearing along some axes, followed by another change of basis.
It is just for the visualization purpose we do all those change of bases and struggle to decompose in a manner that puts in evidence pure shearing along original basis (the diagonal matrix of above decompositions)? 

 Perhaps the most simple and intuitive way to analyze geometrical properties of a linear mapping is to look at the unit sphere (in any dimension, but stick with 3 dimensions for the sake of simplicity). Now, the most general linear mapping sends the unit sphere in an ellipsoid, and it happens that its semiaxes are the singular values of ***A***. Incidentally, the greatest semiaxis is the induced Matrix Norm of ***A***.
All of above has any other purpose apart from visualization?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every linear transformation is a change of basis: it has to be invertible to be so.

Regarding "visualization", that is not the point at all. In fact most of the time people work with matrices, not with linear transformations. And the decompositions you mention give very useful information about the matrix (as they do about the associated linear transformation, of course).

Comment: But, in a broader sense, even a singular linear transformation "induces" a change of basis. Consider a projection, surely singular. In the fewer dimensions of image, the basis has to change (if not so, I point out again, the matrix would be a sort of rectangular identity).